# Скрипт подгрузки страницы из файла

Tags: jquery, ajax, php, css, javascript

Подскажите, пожалуйста, скрипт подгрузки страницы через файл. Мне надо сделать так, чтобы сайт подгружал данные со страницы, а не нумеровал их. Но брал информацию не из базы данных, а из файла.

Comment: Очень сложно понять что Вам нужно. Динамическая загрузка страницы?

Comment: да, чтобы данные из файла(.dat) подгружались ниже, просто у меня нумерация по цифрам, а по дизайну нужна именно подгрузка

Comment: > я очень плохо знаю javascript напишите

...

Теперь, при любом button.onclick, вы будете писать на ХК?..

Comment: Нет, всего раз спросил про javascript

Answer (score 1):

`$('div').load('func.php');` а php уже читает тот самый `dat` и отдает что там.
Можно и через `$('div').ajax()` если требуется передавать в `func.php` какие нибудь параметры (POST) и на основании их как то по другому отдавать.

Comment: Я немного не понял ответа, т.е. при нажатии на ссылку <a href="javascript: loadpage()"> страница должна подгрузиться? Но как она узнает, что именно 10 записей подгрузилось?

Comment: можно всё сразу подгрузить а там дозировать через например $().append()

Comment: я очень плохо знаю javascript
напишите, пожалуйста, пример
самый обычный.)

Comment: ссылка может быть картинкой, кнопкой, блоком чем угодно. просто вешаем на клик по ней функцию, которая делает запрос к php. например $('button').live('click',function(){$('тут блок в который подгружаем').load('тут php файл, который,вернет строки');});